# Booleans etc with Kivy ConfigParser

Tags: python, parsing, types, kivy

I've created a settings.ini and am trying to get my head around the Kivy Config Parser. I'm having to enclose all my 'get' statements in str() for most of it to work, so I wonder if I'm misunderstanding something fundamental. Also, I cannot get booleans to report correctly, so:

**settings.ini**

```
[settings]
option_enabled = False
```

**test.py**

```
from kivy.config import ConfigParser
config = ConfigParser()
config.read('settings.ini')

print(config.get('settings', 'option_enabled'))
```

returns 'False'

```
if config.get('settings', 'option_enabled'):
    print "true"
```

returns 'true'

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue today.
Finally solved by overriding the SettingBoolean.

```
from kivy.uix.settings import Settings, SettingBoolean

class MySettingBoolean(SettingBoolean):
    values = ListProperty(['False', 'True'])

s = Settings()
s.register_type('bool', MySettingBoolean)
```

This keeps the switches in the Settings panel and the True / False values in the ini file.

Answer (score 0):

[edited, as OP changed the question by correcting a typo]

I am not familiar with kivy, and cannot test, but here is my take on it:

I believe that `config.get('settings', 'option_enabled')` returns a string value, so when you enclose this with a `print()` statement, it will print the string value `'False'`

when you use the same in the `if` statement, the string value in the `if` statement will return `'True'` invoking your `print "True"`

can you try that and let me know that is the answer ?

Comment: ah now :-) ... was the correct answer based on your typo :-)

Comment: @user4893295 ... I revised my answer

Comment: So I guess converting the type to boolean would fix it... but seems there's no built in method to do this. Takes away the tidiness of my if statements if I can't use booleans... and in any case is all this converting really necessary, i.e. my wider question?

Comment: well, your first question was "where does I go wrong", I guess that is been answered as config.get returns a string... "is all this converting really necessary?" -- you can certainly do a config.getint (@Yoav beat me to it) but that doesn't negate the fact that you need to validate what config.get or config.getint returns. Users can put values in there which are not validated. When you decide to go int with a value of 0 or 1, it does not stop a user of putting a 2 in the .ini file. You do need to do a validation when you read the value. Validation needed for both int or string. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

As "Edwin van Mierlo" answered, you are getting a string out of config.get...

My suggestion is to use config.getint

ini file

```
[settings]
option_enabled = 0
```

code:

```
if config.getint('settings', 'option_enabled'): #notice the getint instead of get
    print "true"
```

Answer (score 0):

you are facing this problem because python's standard ini parser writes and expects boolean values as True/False, while kivy's ConfigParser expects (and writes) 0/1. That's the reason you are probably seeing panels created with off switchs when indeed they are defined as True in the ini. However, if you save a boolean from kivy's settings panel, you'll see that it will get saved as 1 (contrary to True).
The good part is that python's standard ini parser also understands 0/1.
The bad part is that the default values written by python's standard ini manager are saved as True/False, and when picked up by kivy (since those values are not recognized) they will default to 0 (false).

According to kivy docs you can use a custom form of a BooleanSettings and tell it to  read and write True/False values (instead of 0/1), but I haven't found yet where exactly is that those settings should be instantiated (since everything is done automatically by ConfigParser).

Not a full answer, but hope it helps anyways.